# Problem with fields when working with sqlx in rust

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx, rust-axum

I am working on a REST API written in Rust using axum, sqlx and PostgreSQL.

There are the following two models:

```
#[derive(FromRow, Serialize)]
pub struct Brand {
    id: i32,
    title: String,
    #[sqlx(flatten)]
    product: Product
}

#[derive(FromRow, Serialize)]
pub struct Product {
    title: String,
    id: i32,
}
```

Query code:

```
let rows = query_as::<_, Brand>("SELECT * FROM brands INNER JOIN products ON brands.id = products.brandId")
        .fetch_all(&pool)
        .await
        .unwrap();
```

And I get the following response:

```
{
    "id": 1,   // there should be 4
    "title": "AeroCool VX PLUS 500W",  // there should be just a "AeroCool"
    "product": {
            "title": "AeroCool VX PLUS 500W",
            "id": 1 
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,   // there should be 12
    "title": "Cougar VTE600",  // there should be just a "Cougar"
    "product": {
        "title": "Cougar VTE600",
        "id": 2
    }
},
```

I think this is due to the same field names.

I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear, this is my first time asking a question here.

So far, I see only one way out - this is renaming the fields in the database. But I think it's a bad decision. Tell me, please, what can be done in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using `#[sqlx(flatten)]`

In order to have nesting in sql in general, You can use the postgres json feature instead with the `#[sqlx(json)]` attribute and modifying your inner joins to use json functions.

Use functions like this inside your select clause

`json_build_object() as product` or `json_build_array() as products` depending on whether the type is an object or an array.